# Accessing and replacing values in a Knockout Observable Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I've been having difficulty understanding how Knockout Observable Arrays work, more specifically replacing certain vales within them. I keep thinking I've got it right until further down the line when something else doesn't work correctly.

Due to the complexity of my viewmodel (Observable Arrays of Observable Arrays of Observables with subscriptions to update their respective arrays) I won't post the full extent of my actual issue, especially as there is clearly a fundamental misunderstanding here.

I've essentially got it narrowed down to 2 possibilities, examples below, where; groups = KO Array of observable objects/arrays and rightTargetPropertyName = KO array of obs strings

```
filter().groups()[0].rightTargetPropertyName([ko.observable("placeholder")])[0];
```

The above works but I feel like it will replace the whole array with a single value as the UI grows

```
filter().groups()[0].rightTargetPropertyName()[0]("placeholder");
```

This one above seems like it should be the correct way to change a single observable value in an observable array but the subscriptions/computed values aren't triggered when this code is run.

So in summary, which is the correct way to modify observable values in observable arrays? If the second method is correct (as I suspect) I can debug further.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know you said that you viewmodel was long, but could you still post it? It would make it clearer to visualise your problem

Comment: without seeing any other code the second statement looks ok to me.  if there are subscriptions are not triggering when you expect them to, then check that you are not overwriting/resetting the internal observable array at any point as you will need to setup the subscription again.  also be aware that if you are intentionally resetting the array then it is a good idea teardown the subscriptions before reassigning them to a new observable array